# Configuring Firebug per tab and not per domain

Tags: firebug

I have multiple sites from the same domain open in different tabs.  If each tab has firebug open whenever I move firebug it moves for every tab on that domain.

For example I have google.com open in 3 tabs.  I have firebug open in each one of those tabs.  If i move firebug half way up the screen in one of the tabs.  It moves half way up the screen for every tab.  Does anyone know of some sort of configuration that would save firebug per tab and not per domain?  I have looked at the user groups but they said this issue was fixed many versions ago.

I am on:
Firefox 11.0
Firebug 1.9.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, that is not how Firebug works. However, Firebug 1.10 will be closer to your request than 1.9, but is very very alpha and that feature doesn't work quite as expected yet.

You can try using FireStarter though:

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#FireStarter